# MS Access 2007 ItemData how to display last row?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a question about how to display a last row in the ComboBox in MS Access 2007.

For displaying of the first row as Default Value in the ComboBox i was using the ComboBox.ItemData(0), but my question is how to display the last row as Default Value in the ComboBox?

Kind regards,
lukso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use ListCount in VBA:

```
i = Me.Combo0.ListCount - 1
Me.Combo0 = Me.Combo0.ItemData(i)
```

On the property sheet:

```
Default value: =[Combo0].[Itemdata]([Combo0].[ListCount]-1)
```

Comment: have I to put it as a default value?

Comment: No. The above is code to run in a form event. On Current for example. If you want a default value, you can just use the ID from the table.

Comment: I tried to put this code in the event On Current of my form, and it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? Do you get an error message? Did you change Combo0 to the name of your combo?

Comment: I cannot get the last row as default value in my ComboBox. I get no error message and I changed Combo0 to the name of my ComboBox.

Comment: What is the row source of your combo?

Comment: I select the id and name from my table

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18945/discussion-between-remou-and-lukso)